# MVVM-Light SimpleIoc: Can't create multiple instances dynamically

Tags: mvvm-light, simpleioc

I am building an WPF application using the MVVM Light Toolkit and specifically SimpleIoc.

I have a parent viewmodel that dynamically creates child viewmodels. When doing this I am using "standard" dependency injection to pass a IConfigService as a parameter to the constructor. I want the IConfigService to be a unique instance for each child viewmodel. So I try this:

```
IConfigService service = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IConfigService>(key);
ChildViewModel vm = new ChildViewModel(service);
```

Where *key* is a unique identifier for each child viewmodel. According to the documentation of MVVM Light and SimpleIoc this *GetInstance* method:

> ...provides a way to get an instance of a given type corresponding to a given key. If no instance had been instantiated with this key before, a new instance will be created.

There is also a remark that the class must have been registered before, else it returns null. In my case it has been, in ViewModelLocator:

```
var configService = new ConfigService();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IConfigService>(() => configService);
```

However, the GetInstance call returns the **same** instance every time.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You registered an already instantiated object.

SimpleIoc does not create its own instances with this overload. It always returns `configService`. Either you need to perform the instantiation within the lambda, because you are using a factory overload, or you can do this more easily by just passing the `ConfigService` type. SimpleIoc will take care of the instantiation itself.